# Highcharts stacked bar graph as timeline

Tags: highcharts, timeline

Is there a way to make the Highcharts stacked bar graph work like a timeline? What I'd like to achieve is demonstrated in this [Google Timeline Chart example](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/timeline#AdvancedExample).

Of key importance is that values can be repeated on the same bar. I haven't been able to figure this out, and currently suspect I may need to fall back to the Renderer and draw this chart manually, or switch to Google Charts, both of which I'd prefer to avoid. Thanks for any thoughts!

Comment: Did you ever get anywhere with this?

Comment: 4 years later, yet I am having the same issue. The Google Timeline Chart is exactly what I am looking for but I would rather use Highcharts. There just doesn't seem to be a way.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is possible. This is called a [gantt](http://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-general/suggestions/804783-gantt-chart) chart. That link has various examples. Some dont work. In that case update the jsFiddle's jquery and change the highcharts.js inclusion url.

Comment: Thanks! Sadly, I'd seen that example (and figured out the broken script src :-) But it looks like each row is a separate category with a unique color. In the sample link I sent, each row can contain multiple colors, and some colors can be repeated, both within a row (bar) and across rows. Basically, I'd like to represent device state (say "up"=green, "down"=red) over the X-axis (time), and I'd like to show more than one device, ideally in the same chart. Thanks!

Comment: Actually, this example looks promising at first glance: http://jsfiddle.net/MhL2Q/4/

Comment: Gantt chart is still not live in the stable build and the current commit also has bugs.